# Laravel: Fetch all the values and check it against boolean attribute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need some advice and help on the following topic.

I have a setup of migrations like this.

```
+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|       plates       |   plates_container   |  container_slots   |
+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| id                 | id                   | id                 |
| plate_container_id | number_of_slots(int) | slot               |
| container_slot_id  |                      | occupied (boolean) |
|                    |                      | plate_container_id |
+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

The relations between tables goes like this.

**Plate**

- Plate `belongsTo` a `platecontainer`
- Plate `belongsTo` `containerslot`

**PlateContainer**

- platecontainer `hasMany` `containerSlots`
- platecontainer `hasMany` `plates`

**ContainerSlot**

- ContainerSlot `belongsTo` `plateContainer`
- ContainerSlot `hasOne` `plate`

### Question

How can I (specified by `id`) fetch all the `number_of_slots` and check which of those slots are already `occupied` and which are not.

So to clarify a bit more. A list like this or similar is what I am asking for.

```
slots = [

 1 => false,
 2 => false,
 3 => true, 
 4 => false
//etc

];
```

If you have any other suggestions regarding the database structure, please let me know in the comments. I am slightly doubtful about updating the `occupied` attribute every time after the user chooses a `slot` for the `plate`.

Comment: When you said “how can I (specified by `id`)…”, which `id` in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Eloquent's collection methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections) and [`pluck`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck) will help you. Assuming you have defined your models properly for each of the mentioned tables you can do:

```php
PlateContainer::find($id)
              ->container_slots
              ->pluck('occupied', 'id');
```

This will give you the expected results you are looking for in the following form (which is basically an array):

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1859
     all: [
       1 => true,
       2 => true,
       3 => false,
       4 => true
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Gold! Exactly what I have been looking for! You have guessed good! I meant `id` of a `platecontainer`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.

Comment: I know this is not the original question, but I was just wondering if it's possible to fetch all three attributes (`id`, `slot`, `occupied`) and having those show just like in your above mentioned answer.  I check the docs for it, but could find anything similar .

Comment: There's a 'only' method where you could pass an array of property name.

Comment: I gave this a try. `PlateContainer::find(1)->containerSlots->only('occupied', 'slot', 'id');` only its returning empty array.        just like this                             `Collection {#467
  #items: []
}`

Comment: Wrap the parameters in a array.

Comment: Is it possible to contact you somehow regarding some specific questions? Thanks!